# PHP producing incorrect arithmetic results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script which launches a mysql query and returns a result set with aggregated columns.

I need to do further aggregations on these column, and as such have done so in my script.

The problem is that for the first 7 results out of the 20 limit, the calculations are blatantly incorrect.

Is this something to do with the fact that the table is large? (3.5m rows)

Can I complete the extra aggregations at the SQL level? say `A` is an aggregation and `B` is an aggregation, can I do column `C = B / A`?

[image: Output]

```
//QUERY
        $resultsquery = $db->prepare("SELECT 4_nationality.nationality, COUNT(DISTINCT(txn_id)) as numtrans,
                                        SUM(sales) as sales, SUM(units) as units, YrQtr
                                        FROM 1_txns INNER JOIN 4_nationality USING (nationality_id)
                                        WHERE YrQtr LIKE :period
                                        GROUP BY nationality_id 
                                        ORDER BY numtrans DESC
                                        LIMIT 20");
        $resultsquery->bindParam(":period", $period);
        $resultsquery->execute();

        //BUILD TABLE

        echo "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-10'>";
        echo $select;


        echo "<table class='table table-striped'><tr>";
            echo "<th>Nationality</th>";
            echo "<th># Trans</th>";
            echo "<th>Sales</th>";
            echo "<th>Units</th>";
            echo "<th>ATV</th>";
            echo "<th>UPB</th>";
            echo "<th>ARP</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while($row2 = $resultsquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            //FURTHER CALCULATIONS

            $nat = $row2['nationality'];
            $numtrans = number_format($row2['numtrans'], 0);
            $sales = number_format($row2['sales'], 0);
            $units = number_format($row2['units'], 0);
            $atvc = $sales / $numtrans;
            $atv = number_format($atvc, 2);
            $upbc = $units / $numtrans;
            $upb = number_format($upbc, 1);
            $arpc = $sales / $units;
            $arp = number_format($arpc, 2);

                //DISPLAY
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$nat."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$numtrans."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$sales."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$units."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$atv."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$upb."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$arp."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

        }

        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";
```

Edit: many thanks for both of the answers, it was difficult to choose which to accept as they both helped me in different ways. I have however decided to accept the answer which offers more detail regarding the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be because you are performing arithmetic on formatted strings.

Try:

```
$nat = $row2['nationality'];
$numtrans = number_format($row2['numtrans'], 0);
$sales = number_format($row2['sales'], 0);
$units = number_format($row2['units'], 0);
$atvc = $row2['sales'] / $row2['numtrans'];
$atv = number_format($atvc, 2);
$upbc = $row2['units'] / $row2['numtrans'];
$upb = number_format($upbc, 1);
$arpc = $row2['sales'] / $row2['units'];
$arp = number_format($arpc, 2);
```

Edit:

Actually I'm sure this is whats happenning:

```
echo '15,263,316' / '568,393'; // 0.026408450704225
echo 15263316 / 568393;        //26.853455267746
```

Answer (score 2):

It didn't work because you were calculating with formatted numbers like `27,002,864` instead of `27002864`.
And yes, it is easier in SQL:

```
SELECT 4_nationality.nationality, COUNT(DISTINCT(txn_id)) as numtrans,
  SUM(sales) as sales, SUM(units) as units, YrQtr, 
  sum(sales)/count(distinct txn_id) atvc, 
  sum(units)/count(distinct txn_id) upbc, 
  sum(sales)/sum(units) arp
FROM 1_txns INNER JOIN 4_nationality USING (nationality_id)
WHERE YrQtr LIKE :period
GROUP BY nationality_id 
ORDER BY numtrans DESC
LIMIT 20
```